# How do I run a calculation in my ruby on rails model before the view is rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application where users complete a number of tests. The results of these tests is then stored in the database.

```
class TestOne < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  before_save :calculate_total

private 

  def calculate_total
    self.total = self.question_1 + self.question_2
  end
end
```

I then have a summary page which performs some calculations (in the summary page model) and then these values are displayed on the summary page.

```
class Summary < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.amount
    amount = 0
    @users.each do |u|
       if u.test_ones.present?
          amount += 1
       else
       end

       if u.test_twos.present?
       else
       end

       return amount
   end
 end
```

The problem I am having is that the calculations (amount) do not update when new data is saved. I am assuming there is some code I can put in the model to make it recalculate before the summary view is rendered (similar to the `before_save` in the other model)?

Thanks in advance x

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before_action` or `before_filter` (deprecates in  Rails 5.1) in your controller (the controller *control's* presenting the view layer  and the model handles the logic of the records. Depending on how complex your action is, this may be a bad solution. If it takes a long time, or the flow gets complex, then it is better to keep this out of the controller. See [this](http://craftingruby.com/posts/2015/05/31/dont-use-before-action-to-load-data.html) post for more info. Also note the render flow in this example:

```
def update
  if @tree.update(tree_params) # Render / Re-route based on truthy.
    redirect_to(@tree)
  else
    render('edit')
  end
end
```

However, there are other libraries that specifically handle things like this. For example, ReactJs will automatically re-render components when the 'properties' or 'state' of the component changes. It may be too much overhead to implement React just for this, but if you anticipate having lots of dynamic page data it may be better to use some facet of javascript to automate view layer components.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I seem to have solved it just by setting up associations between my summary model and the test models. Is that an appropriate way of fixing?

Comment: If it works and you're happy maintaining the code then sure.